# libgdx/box2d lights: change blur of lights

Tags: libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the rate at which a lights intensity decareases over distance.

something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figuered it out.
You have to write a custom shader that is essetially the same as the default one, but change the line that takes care of the interpolation:

```
"v_color = s*quad_colors;\n"
```

for example:

```
"v_color = s*2*quad_colors;\n"
```

halves the dropoff rate, while:

```
"v_color = (s*0)+quad_colors;\n"
```

gets rid of any blur (leaving out the "s" completely out won't work)

Comment: You mean the default vertex shader? But the default vertex shader doesn't have any `s` or `quad_colors` variables...? My default vertex shader is `v_color = a_color;`.

Answer (score -1):

I have the "v_color = s*quad_colors;\n" its in the vertex shader of the light source. See https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/blob/master/src/shaders/LightShader.java. However the above didn't work for me, the number you use must be a float. E.g."v_color = (s*0.0)+quad_colors;\n"